# Howto dig for performance problems with moxy

Tags: java, performance, moxy

I'm using moxy for large structure and in 95% of cases it works like charme. It is fast and reliable. But I do have now a project with the same class structure but different data. Now I do have a big read impact. Writing the complete project needs ~20sec, but reading needs more than 450sec. The written file is around 280MB. (Usally reading is only 30% slower)

With guessing I wasn't able to find the problem. But how to dig for this problem in moxy.

The first thing I tried was to supply a different Reader (BufferedInputStream, FileInputStream and just the file) nothing changed. Than I checked the XmlJavaTypeAdapter and set the defaultSize of maps etc. Again nothing changed.

So maybe someone has a better idea.

**[UPDATE 1]**

After extracting all osgi parts and building a standalone java application I was able to use VisualVM for analyzing this project. And I found that ReferenceResolver.getReference() consumes more than 90%. So I guess my Reference and ID is somehow badly designed.

**[UPDATE 2]**

Created an [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437920)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discovered a performance bug.

It was addressed and the algorithm has been changed, decreasing time complexity roughly by n (size of input). Should be pretty fast now. May moxy charm you in 100 % of cases.

Thanks for the contribution.